# How to set variable to Properties.Settings.Default instead of setting name?

Tags: c#, .net

For example I do save to App.config like this:

```
int SaveInteger = %ANY INTEGER%
Properties.Settings.Default.X_Position = SaveInteger;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

---

I make a string variable that contains the name of the setting, depending on the work of the program:

```
string Some_Setting = %ANY SETTING NAME%;
```

So the main question is how i can set variable Some_Setting to Properties.Settings.Default.%SettingName% instead of setting name?

Comment: If I am not mistaken and remember correctly, it should be possible to do `Properties.Settings.Default["settingName"] = whateverValue`? I'll check again ...

Comment: ^^ Yep, _should_ work. Cannot test it at this moment, but the base class has [ApplicationSettingsBase.Item\[String\] Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.item?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-configuration-applicationsettingsbase-item(system-string))

Comment: @Fildor Oh yeah that's what i need! Didn't read the documentation carefully :). You can answer for this question to close it because is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base class has the `Item[String]` Property.

That means you can do

```
Properties.Settings.Default["settingName"] = whateverValue;
```

For reference: [ApplicationSettingsBase.Item[String] Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.item?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-configuration-applicationsettingsbase-item(system-string))